# How do I include a file in Apache config without generating an error when it doesn't exist?

Tags: apache

This is for a shared config file that should include another file if it exists, but still work otherwise. If I do

```
Include foo.conf
```

and foo.conf doesn't exist, apache will complain:

```
could not open document config file /etc/httpd/conf/foo.conf
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I came up with a clever solution, though there may be a better way. Put one of the characters in brackets so Apache will treat it as a glob pattern, which is allowed to match zero files without causing an error. E.g.:

```
Include foo.con[f]
```

Comment: Nice trick. You could also use `*`. I would recommend putting your conf files in an unike folder and include like this `Include myfolder/*.conf`

Comment: Clever indeed! I prefer [f] rather * as its a bit less risky

Comment: @fedmich. Good idea, as using * can cause multiple includes to get included in an unexpected order which can cause unexpected behavior when order matters.

Comment: I can't get this trick working...all I got is "No such file or directory" error as it seems apache treats the brackets literal as part of the file name...not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: This no longer works now.. Get this error `No matches for the wildcard 'extra.con[f]' in '/home/www/site', failing`. But the `IncludeOptional` answer below this is definitely working!

Answer (score 48):

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include you could use "IncludeOptional":

> Alternatively, the following command will just be ignored in case of missing files or directories:
>
> IncludeOptional conf/vhosts/*/*.conf

Comment: Note: This only works in Apache 2.3.6 and newer (effectively 2.4+)

Comment: Key thing about IncludeOptional is that if you give it a literal path with no glob operators, it will definitely error if it does not find that path (the docs don't make that clear). Otherwise, an unmatched globular path with Include will error out while one with IncludeOptional will be silently ignored.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work completely as I would expect. I started out with trying this:

    `IncludeOptional /opt/data/sites/*/conf/apache.conf`

Which fails if any direcotry in /opt/data/sites does not have a directory 'conf'.

So, I tried creating the 'conf' directory for all sites. But still no luck. As mentioned previously mentioned by Russel Davis, the file part needs to be a wildcard. So now I have:

    `IncludeOptional /opt/data/sites/*/conf/vhost-*.conf`

Comment: IncludeOptional will fail on a missing path for versions prior to 2.4.30. The easiest way to get around this is the glob trick in one of the other answers, but  surround the first character of each path segment with '[]', that will prevent it from failing.

Answer (score 7):

```
IncludeOptional foo.conf
```

Apache httpd version 2.3.6 and later

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#includeoptional

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same as Wouter Van Vliet, but I still got errors. Then I found [this link](http://rolandtapken.de/blog/2012-07/apache-include-directive-wildcards). I added this snippet to my */etc/apache2/apache2.conf* and it works like a charm!

Note: You need *mod_perl* for it!

Here is the code:

```
<perl>
    use File::stat;
    foreach $file (glob '/srv/www/vhosts/*/conf/vhost.conf') {
        my $stat = stat($file);
        if ($stat-&gt;uid != 0 || $stat-&gt;gid != 0) {
            warn "$file is not owned by root:root, skipping!\n";
            next;
        }
        if ($stat-&gt;mode &amp; 0002) {
            warn "$file is world-writable, skipping!\n";
            next;
        }
        push @Include, $file;
    }
</perl>
```